# Explicit geometry bounds

Tags: wpf, xaml, drawing, geometry

I encountered following problem during creation of radioactive geometry:
[image: Radioactive geometry]

Orange dot represents RadialGradientBrush center point (0,0). It should be in the center of black circle, not on the bottom. This cause another problem: spinning animation.

Is there a way to fix this at the geometry level ? I could fix it by setting brush's center point explicitly, but that is inconvenient and brittle.

```
<GeometryDrawing> 
    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        <GeometryGroup>
            <PathGeometry Figures="
                          M-10,0 Q0,5 10,0
                          Q20,25 25,50
                          Q0,60 -25,50
                          Q-20,25 -10,0 Z">
                <PathGeometry.Transform>
                    <TranslateTransform Y="15" />
                </PathGeometry.Transform>
            </PathGeometry>

            <PathGeometry Figures="
                          M-10,0 Q0,5 10,0
                          Q20,25 25,50
                          Q0,60 -25,50
                          Q-20,25 -10,0 Z" >
                <PathGeometry.Transform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <TranslateTransform Y="15" />
                        <RotateTransform Angle="120" />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </PathGeometry.Transform>
            </PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures="
                          M-10,0 Q0,5 10,0
                          Q20,25 25,50
                          Q0,60 -25,50
                          Q-20,25 -10,0 Z" >
                <PathGeometry.Transform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <TranslateTransform Y="15" />
                        <RotateTransform Angle="240" />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </PathGeometry.Transform>
            </PathGeometry>
            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" />
        </GeometryGroup>
    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
    <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
        <RadialGradientBrush ColorInterpolationMode="ScRgbLinearInterpolation">
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Orange" />
            <GradientStop Offset="0.03" Color="Black" />
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
        <Pen Thickness="0">
            <Pen.Brush>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" />
            </Pen.Brush>
        </Pen>
    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
</GeometryDrawing>
```

Comment: "radioactive geometry", that sounds funny, kind of like "[forgiven geometry](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nP0lJciMN8M)"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that the top of the box cuts off the top of the big circle. It is cut off because the top two petals are rotated.

You could fix this by adding the outer circle (transparent) to the geometry or perhaps by adding a margin to the top.

this will move down the black parts of the drawing, centering the orange dot and fixing the rotation.

Does this make sense? It is hard to explain, when needed I could create a sketch.

Comment: Can't find something like geometry margin :)

Outer circle is fine. It solved rotation origin problem.

Brush origin problem still remains. Only one brush per GeometryDrawing is allowed. The outer circle has to be in different GeometryDrawing in order to be invisible, so it does not affect other brushes, but I can live with that :)

Thanks

Comment: You could stack multiple GeometryDrawings in a DrawingGroup. You're welcome.